# How can I use jQuery AJAX to update my Gridview?

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have a gridview with rows that can be edited, inserted etc.  I wrapped it in an updatepanel to give it an AJAX effect and update the system without reloading the page.  I recently got into using jQuery and webservices for my AJAX calls and I absolutely love how it works and how fast it is.  I would like to know if it is possible, and if so then how, to update my gridview using jQuery AJAX methods.

Comment: If you have a method to reload the GridView with a xml o json, I suppose you could just get this data from server via ajax then just reload the grid, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to seriously jerryrig the thing to get this to work. Not something I would recommend.

If you want to use jQuery AJAX I'd recommend scrapping the GridView and using a Repeater instead.